# How to disable Paypal method for a specific customer group?

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, customer-group

I'm actually using a payment filter by customer group extension on my magento 1.9 CE. That let me control which payment method can have access my clients based on their customer group. Unfortunately this filter doesn't seem to apply to Paypal Express (it shows up anyway for all clients). Any idea?

*Mod edit: [extension code publicly available on GitHub](https://github.com/netz98/N98_CheckoutFilters).*

Comment: This is the extension i'm using right now to filter payment: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/n98-checkout-filters.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the solution. I'll share it others.

In case you need this extension for PayPal (Magento CE 1.7.0)
some minor changes would do the trick:

```
N98_CustomerGroupCheckout_Block_Adminhtml_System_Config_Form
OLD:
if (isset($subGroup->fields)) {
$this->_addFieldToConfigGroup($subGroup);
}
NEW:
if (isset($subGroup->fields)) {
if($subGroup->getName()!='account' && substr($subGroup->getName(),0,6)!='paypal'){
$this->_addFieldToConfigGroup($subGroup);
}
if(isset($subGroup->fields->wps)) {
$this->_addFieldToConfigGroup($subGroup->fields->wps);
}
if(isset($subGroup->fields->express_checkout)) {
$this->_addFieldToConfigGroup($subGroup->fields->express_checkout);
}
}
N98_CustomerGroupCheckout_Model_Payment_Observer
OLD:
if ($paymentMethodInstance instanceof Mage_Paypal_Model_Standard) {
$customerGroupConfig = Mage::getStoreConfig('paypal/wps/' . self::XML_CUSTOMER_GROUP_CONFIG_FIELD);
} elseif ($paymentMethodInstance instanceof Mage_Paypal_Model_Express) {
$customerGroupConfig = Mage::getStoreConfig('paypal/express/' . self::XML_CUSTOMER_GROUP_CONFIG_FIELD);
} elseif ($paymentMethodInstance instanceof Mage_GoogleCheckout_Model_Payment) {
$customerGroupConfig = Mage::getStoreConfig('google/checkout/' . self::XML_CUSTOMER_GROUP_CONFIG_FIELD);
} else {
$customerGroupConfig = $paymentMethodInstance->getConfigData(self::XML_CUSTOMER_GROUP_CONFIG_FIELD);
}
NEW:
if ($paymentMethodInstance instanceof Mage_Paypal_Model_Standard) {
$customerGroupConfig = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/wps/' . self::XML_CUSTOMER_GROUP_CONFIG_FIELD);
} elseif ($paymentMethodInstance instanceof Mage_Paypal_Model_Express) {
$customerGroupConfig = Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/express_checkout/' . self::XML_CUSTOMER_GROUP_CONFIG_FIELD);
} elseif ($paymentMethodInstance instanceof Mage_GoogleCheckout_Model_Payment) {
$customerGroupConfig = Mage::getStoreConfig('google/checkout/' . self::XML_CUSTOMER_GROUP_CONFIG_FIELD);
} else {
$customerGroupConfig = $paymentMethodInstance->getConfigData(self::XML_CUSTOMER_GROUP_CONFIG_FIELD);
}
```